# how to shift an xts time series to the left in r?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, xts

I am trying to shift one column of an xts time series to the left in R (please see the code below). The lag shifts nicely to the right, but I want it to line up with the rolling mean. Using a negative number says: "n must be positive".

```
#rm(list=ls())
#dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"])
library(roll) # do not use library(RcppRoll)!
getSymbols("^GSPC",src="yahoo",from="2015-01-01",to = "2020-06-04")
y<-GSPC$GSPC.Close
standardize<-function(ts) { as.xts(apply(ts, 2, function(x) x / x[1])) }
y<-standardize(GSPC$GSPC.Close)
n=400
y$m<-rollmean(y$GSPC.Close,k=n)
y$rolling<-roll_sd(y$GSPC.Close,n)
y$lag<-lag(y$rolling,n/2) # how to go left?
plot(y)
ts.plot(y,col=1:4)
```

Comment: try ```lead()``` instead of ```lag()```.

Comment: duh, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative value for `n` when you call `lag()` on an xts object. This works:

```r
library(quantmod)
gspc <- getSymbols("^GSPC", from = "2015-01-01", to = "2020-06-04", auto.assign = FALSE)
standardize <- function(ts) { as.xts(apply(ts, 2, function(x) x / x[1])) }
y <- standardize(Cl(gspc))
n <- 400
y$m <- rollapply(Cl(y), k = n, mean)
y$rolling <- rollapply(Cl(y), n, sd)
y$lag  <- lag(y$rolling,  n/2)
y$lead <- lag(y$rolling, -n/2)
plot(y)
```

You get the error, "n must be positive" because you also have dplyr loaded. You have to be very careful using `lag()` with dplyr loaded because dplyr breaks how base R's `lag()` function is supposed to work. That breaks `lag(my_xts)` and also breaks `lag()` for all other types of objects that have their own `lag()` method (e.g. zoo, ts, etc).